# Grouping / Aggregation and Selection in Pandas DataFrame at the same time

Tags: python, r, grouping, selection, aggregation

I would like to apply an aggregation function (sum()) to a variable ("PurchAmount") which I first aggregate by the dimension "Customer". At the same time I would like to select the column "Quantity".

In R this is possible with:

```
myData[, list(Quantity, AggPurch=sum(PurchAmount)), by=Customer]
```

Is there a similar solution for Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Comment: @Rich Scriven  My only edit was removing the spurious R tag for this question.  If not through an edit,  how should that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can split a pandas into groups using '.groupby':

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'], 
    'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'], 
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

df['preTestScore'].groupby([df['regiment'], df['company']]).mean()
```

The output for df will be:

```
regiment    company
Dragoons    1st         3.5
            2nd        27.5
Nighthawks  1st        14.0
            2nd        16.5
Scouts      1st         2.5
            2nd         2.5
dtype: float64
```

Example from:
http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html